# How can I prevent Bootstrap3 from wrapping col classes to the next line?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a list of links with a button pulled to the right of each link. The issue is that the button gets wrapped to the next line on a small screen when the link is very large. I would like the link to take up all the space left after the button and not wrap to the next line. Preferably I would like the link to be displayed as a btn as well but figured that was innescessary for the question.

Here's an example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q3s320j2/12/)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <p>
            <a href="#">link1</a>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-right">Button</button>
        </p>
        <p>
            <a href="#">link2</a>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-right">Button</button>
        </p>
        <p>
            <a href="#">very long link that pushes the button to next line</a>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-right">Button</button>
        </p>
        <p>
            <a href="#">link4</a>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-right">Button</button>
        </p>
        <p>
            <a href="#">link5</a>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-right">Button</button>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried every no-wrap property and changing the width of the p's but nothing seems to work and I'm now stumped. Also if anyone has any insight into why changing the p elements to div elements messes up the layout that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it you're looking to conditionally apply ellipsis based on whether there's enough space to display the full text or not.

First, you need to apply your standard three ellipsis rules:

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Then you'll need to set **[`display: inline-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)** so that the overflow (and subsequent ellipsis) can take effect, without messing up the layout.

Finally, and most importantly, you'll want to set a calculation-driven **[`max-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width)** by using the **[`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)** function. Set a width of `100%`, and subtract the width of the button from it. In this case, you're looking for `max-width: calc(100% - 47px)`. The magic is that as you resize the page, the inherited **[`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width)** will change, yet you'll still leave enough space for the button. This results in the full text being shown when it's possible to do so, and ellipsis being added when it is not possible.

This can all be seen in the following:

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');
.no-deco,
.no-deco:link,
.no-deco:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: darkslategray;
}

.no-deco:hover,
.no-deco:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: darkgray;
}

.no-deco {
  max-width: calc(100% - 47px);
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <p>
        <a class="no-deco" href="#">link</a>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-right">Button</button>
      </p>
      <p>
        <a class="no-deco" href="#">link</a>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-right">Button</button>
      </p>
      <p>
        <a class="no-deco" href="#">very long link that pushes button to next line</a>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-right">Button</button>
      </p>
      <p>
        <a class="no-deco" href="#">link</a>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-right">Button</button>
      </p>
      <p>
        <a class="no-deco" href="#">link</a>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-right">Button</button>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This can also be seen **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/kj9967he/)**.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. This solution is exactly what I was looking for!